# How to show that a seperatrix exists for the Fisher-KPP equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, applications

We have the Fisher-KPP equation: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + ru(1-u)$

We can reduce this to a second order ODE: $cu_{\xi} = u_{\xi\xi}+u(1-u)$ where $\xi = x+ct$. We can rewrite this as a system of 2 first-order equations,

$u' = V$
$V' = cV-u(1-u)$

Clearly the fixed points are $(U,V) = (0,0), (1,0)$.

#### Question:

How can we show that a seperatrix exists, which connects the 2 equilibrium points. Our hint is that for $c\geq2$ no trajectories can enter the triangle,T given by:

$0\leq u\leq1$ and $0\leq V\leq \frac{cu}{2}$.

We sort of verified this graphically, by plotting the phase plane, but I am not sure that that is enough to show the existence of the speratrix.

Comment: Actually, trajectories can enter the triangle through segment $ V = \frac{cu}{2}, \; 0 \leqslant u \leqslant 1 $ (and they exit through its other sides). Are you sure that you've got correctly what your lecturer said?